# Last set of form element is missing

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I am currently making a form page. However, it seems like my last set of form element is missing. However, my other form elements are present, except for the "Less than/Equal" one which is not appearing. I will add a picture at the end how it is looking right now.

```
<form>
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-title title-a">From</div>
        <div class="ui-block-title title-b"> To</div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" name="From" id="From" required /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="text" name="To" id="To" required /></div>
    </div>

    Conversion Rate
    <input type="text" name="conversionrate" id="conversionrate" required />


    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-title title-a">Greater/Equal</div>
        <div class="ui-block-title title-b"> Comment</div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" name="greaterequal" id="greaterequal" required /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="text" name="greaterequalcomment" id="greaterequalcomment" required /></div>
    </div>


    <div class="ui-grid-e">
        <div class="ui-block-title title-a">Between</div>
        <div class="ui-block-title title-b">Comment</div>
        <div class=ui-block-a><input type="text" name="between1" id="between1" required /></div>
        <div class=ui-block-b><input type="text" name="between2" id="between2" required /></div>
        <div class=ui-block-c><input type="text" name="betweencomment" id="betweencomment" required /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-title title-a">Less than/Equal</div>
        <div class="ui-block-title title-b"> Comment</div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" name="lessthanequal" id="lessthanequal" required /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="text" name="lessthanequal" id="lessthanequalcomment" required /></div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="btnCalculate" value="Calculate" />
</form>
```

Edit - I have added in the CSS as requested:

```
.ui-grid-a,
.ui-grid-b,
.ui-grid-c,
.ui-grid-d,
.ui-grid-solo {
overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-block-a,
.ui-block-b,
.ui-block-c,
.ui-block-d,
.ui-block-e {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
float: left;
min-height: 1px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* force new row */
.ui-block-a {
clear: left;
}

ul.ui-grid-a,
ul.ui-grid-b,
ul.ui-grid-c,
ul.ui-grid-d,
ul.ui-grid-solo,
li.ui-block-a,
li.ui-block-b,
li.ui-block-c,
li.ui-block-d,
li.ui-block-e {
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

/* No margin in grids for 100% width button elements until we can use max-width: fill-available; */
[class*="ui-block-"] > button.ui-btn {
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
}

[class*="ui-block-"] > .ui-btn,
[class*="ui-block-"] > .ui-select,
[class*="ui-block-"] > .ui-checkbox,
[class*="ui-block-"] > .ui-radio,
[class*="ui-block-"] > button.ui-btn-inline,
[class*="ui-block-"] > button.ui-btn-icon-notext,
.ui-header [class*="ui-block-"] > button.ui-btn,
.ui-footer [class*="ui-block-"] > button.ui-btn {
margin-right: .3125em;
margin-left: .3125em;
}

.ui-grid-a > .ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-a > .ui-block-b {
/* width: 49.95%; IE7 */
/* margin-right: -.5px; BB5 */
width: 50%;
}

.ui-grid-b > .ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-b > .ui-block-b,
.ui-grid-b > .ui-block-c {
/* width: 33.25%; IE7 */
/* margin-right: -.5px; BB5 */
width: 33.333%;
}

.ui-grid-c > .ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-c > .ui-block-b,
.ui-grid-c > .ui-block-c,
.ui-grid-c > .ui-block-d {
/* width: 24.925%; IE7 */
/* margin-right: -.5px; BB5 */
width: 25%;
}

.ui-grid-d > .ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-d > .ui-block-b,
.ui-grid-d > .ui-block-c,
.ui-grid-d > .ui-block-d,
.ui-grid-d > .ui-block-e {
/* width: 19.925%; IE7 */
width: 20%;
}

.ui-grid-solo > .ui-block-a {
width: 100%;
float: none; 
}

.ui-grid-e {
position: relative;
width: 400px;
}

.ui-block-a,
.ui-block-b,
.ui-block-c {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0 5px;
}

.ui-block-a {
padding-left: 0;
}

.title-c {
padding-left: 5px;
}

.ui-block-title {
box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

.ui-block-a,
.ui-block-b {
width: 22.5%;
}

.ui-block-c {
width: 50%;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIOFZ.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use below HTML code:

```
<form>
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-title title-a">From</div>
    <div class="ui-block-title title-b"> To</div>
    <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" name="From" id="From" 
required /></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="text" name="To" id="To" required />
</div>
</div>

Conversion Rate
<input type="text" name="conversionrate" id="conversionrate" required />


<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-title title-a">Greater/Equal</div>
    <div class="ui-block-title title-b"> Comment</div>
    <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" name="greaterequal" 
id="greaterequal" required /></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="text" name="greaterequalcomment" 
id="greaterequalcomment" required /></div>
</div>


<div class="ui-grid-e">
    <div class="ui-block-title title-a">Between</div>
    <div class="ui-block-title title-b">Comment</div>
    <div class=ui-block-a><input type="text" name="between1" id="between1" 
required /></div>
    <div class=ui-block-b><input type="text" name="between2" id="between2" 
required /></div>
    <div class=ui-block-c><input type="text" name="betweencomment" 
id="betweencomment" required /></div>
</div>

<div class="ui-block-a">
    <div class="ui-block-title title-a">Less than/Equal</div>
    <div class="ui-block-title title-b"> Comment</div>
    <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" name="lessthanequal" 
id="lessthanequal" required /></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="text" name="lessthanequal" 
id="lessthanequalcomment" required /></div>
</div>

<div class="ui-block-a">
    <div><input type="button" id="btnCalculate" value="Calculate" /></div>
</div>
</form>
```

You can also check at `https://jsfiddle.net/nzw91xw0/4/`

Hope it works!

Comment: @pokeybit Yes you are right! I wrote it by mistake, now corrected

Comment: Don't edit your post if you're wrong, now the comments appear wrong when this is in fact incorrect. Just a heads up :)

Comment: @pokybit I think issue is with type=button. he must use type="submit"

Comment: He may be sending the form with javascript.That is irrelevant. But please. you took my information from my post and used it in your answer as an edit. That's a little sneaky

Comment: @AmitGupta Hello!! I have made changes to the name value for the last set of form elements (for Less than/Equal). However, the whole line of form elements are still not appearing.

Comment: @yxlxn Have you used type="submit" in place of "type="button"

Comment: @AmitGupta I believe that the problem does not lie with the button.

Comment: @yxlxn Then how will you submit the form? Are you submitting with javascript? Also there is no action. Are you redirecting the form to the same page?

Comment: @AmitGupta Seems like you missed the mark here or I have explained myself wrongly. I have yet to code the buttons yet hence, there is nothing wrong with it right now. I have a bigger problem then submitting my buttons currently it makes no sense that I would be starting to code the submitting form button. I have a total of 5 rows of form element. However, I have 4 rows of form element appearing on my app and my last row is not appearing. Why would I start to code my form submission when my whole entire row is not appearing?/ :x

Comment: @yxlxn Now the question is very much clear. Can you please share the CSS as well?

Comment: @yxlxn In HTML there is no issue, all fields are appearing. Please check at https://jsfiddle.net/nzw91xw0/

Comment: @AmitGupta I have added in the CSS. As you can see the picture I had attached at the end, the last row is not appearing. :<

Comment: @yxlxn Wait for few minutes. I will correct and send you back.

Comment: @yxlxn now use the updated code in my answer. Please replace html. hope it will work.

Comment: @yxlxn now 5th row must appear. just you need to do some formatting with fields. https://jsfiddle.net/nzw91xw0/4/

Comment: @AmitGupta yes, the 5th row has appeared. Will make the necessary adjustments. Thank you so much for taking your time in helping me!! Have a nice day!! :-)

Comment: Welcome @yxlxn Please don't forgot to accept my answer and upvote. Happy coding!